# Spring MVC Neo4jConfiguration class not found

Tags: spring, neo4j

I am learning Spring MVC. I want to extend the Neo4jConfiguration class but it is not available. I imported the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

and after that I have reimported the libraries from maven. As I know I should now be able to extend the Neo4jConfiguration class. What is the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Neo4jConfiguration has been dropped from Spring Data Neo4j 4.2.

You can refer to the 'Configuring a Simple Spring Application' and 'Configuring Web Applications' in the [Upgrading to Spring Data Neo4j 4.2](https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/09/30/upgrading-to-sdn-42.html) for a quick configuration without it.

The code sample they provide for simple configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "org.neo4j.example.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class MyNeo4jConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        // with domain entity base package(s)
        return new SessionFactory("org.neo4j.example.domain");
    }
    @Bean
    public Neo4jTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(sessionFactory());
    }
}
```