# Updating a Maven dependancy

Tags: java, spring, maven

**Question**

How do I update my maven spring data neo4j dependancy to the current version?

**Background**

I am just starting to contribute to a certain project, and the first task is updating some functionalities for `spring-data-neo4j`. But, we need to update to the current version first. From `4.1.3` to `4.2.7` so that I can implement these functionalities

We use Maven for handling dependencies. Sadly, I am new to Java and Maven and the code base :( .

I have tried updating the pom.xml file from 4.1.3 to 4.2.7 on this code on the .pom file manually.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-neo4j</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.7.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

But the running it begins to error out with this message:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.1.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project my-service: An exception occurred while running. null: InvocationTargetException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [my.Application]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/data/neo4j/config/Neo4jConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist -> [Help 1]
```

I got the most recent version from this page: https://projects.spring.io/spring-data-neo4j/

I get the feeling that I am supposed to be using maven CLI to update this effectively. But, I can't find any resources on how to update from one version of a dependancy to another via CLI.

**UPDATE 1**

I have tried adding this to the `repositories` list but i still get the same error.

```
    <repository>
        <id>spring-libs-release</id>
        <name>Spring Releases</name>
        <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

This move was suggested here: https://graphaware.com/neo4j/2016/09/30/upgrading-to-sdn-42.html

Comment: Why do you think that issue is maven related and not just based on the issue that you code just doesn't support this new version?

Answer (score 1):

The error is happening when your code is trying to compile; there is an import statement trying to bring in a class that cannot be found.   After some quick quick Googling, it seems that class, `Neo4jConfiguration`, was dropped from the `spring-data-neo4j` dependency.  Go through your code and make sure that the classes you are importing are found in the dependencies you are pulling in.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44888741/spring-mvc-neo4jconfiguration-class-not-found) post seems to cover the exact update you are attempting.